# Aggregate data table with column names as strings

Tags: r, data.table

I want to aggregate a column of a R data table but providing the column names as strings. Is it possible to do it using data table capabilities?

For example, I want to reproduce:

```
foo[,newcol:=mean(oldcol), by=id]
```

but using strings for column names, something like:

```
foo[,"newcol":=mean("oldcol"), by="id"]
```

I have tried:

```
foo[,"newcol":=mean(foo[["oldcol"]]), by="id"]
```

that works, but it is slow as it does not take full advantage of the data table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `get`:

```
 foo[,"newcol":=mean(get("oldcol")), by="id"]
```

But I am not sure that you will have the same performance as without using `get`.

Comment: It is slower than the official way, but much faster thant what I was doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `get` is the generic way, but for this particular case, it's probably faster to do:

```
foo[, "newcol" := lapply(.SD, mean), by = "id", .SDcols = "oldcol"]
```